# How is it possible to make random/pseudorandom numbers in the MOVE language?

Tags: blockchain, move

I am writing a modue in the move language for Sui, I cannot find any doc regarding generating random number in the language?

any suggestion?

I checked this before
https://move-book.com/

Comment: I found the answer: here there is a package for that (which does not seem to be well-secured): https://github.com/Origin-Byte/originmate